# LLVM: run-time error in creating a function of empty input and output

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to create an empty function in LLVM IR

```
void foo(){
}
```

I use

```
LLVMContext Context;
std::unique_ptr<Module> Owner(new Module("test", Context));
Module *M = Owner.get();    
Function *foo =
cast<Function>(M->getOrInsertFunction("foo", Type::getVoidTy(Context),
                                      Type::getVoidTy(Context),
                                      (Type *)0));
```

which compiles but gives me this error *at run time*:

llvm-3.7.src/lib/IR/Type.cpp:350: llvm::FunctionType::FunctionType(llvm::Type*, llvm::ArrayRef, bool): Assertion `isValidArgumentType(Params[i]) && "Not a valid type for function argument!"' failed.
*** Crashed with return code: 0 ***

Any idea about How can we do this `void foo(){}` function in LLVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Void isn't a valid argument type. Use void only for the return type and then pass in null to make an empty argument list.